# IE9 scroll within iframe

Tags: internet-explorer, 7.5

I'd like to ask you whether it's possible to scroll within an iframe on a webpage using IE9 on WP7.5.
I tried to do so on my Lumia 800. I tried the two-finger scroll gesture as it works for example on iPhone but without success.

Is there a special gesture to achieve this or is it simply impossible?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this on any particular website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kinds of elements are difficult on a small touchscreen device. However, to scroll within those elements, you just have to drag to scroll, just like the regular page, except you have to start the scroll gesture inside the iframe element itself.

Comment: sorry for late reply... My problem was on a particular website (Call of Duty Elite, if I remember right). I tried this but that website is doing quite crazy things anyways so I think your answer is correct and the website messed it up.